# How to sort signal data, dropping noise?

Tags: matlab

This is a Matlab question.

I have an array of numbers. Some of them correspond to actual signal, the others correspond to noise. I know that

- The numbers corresponding to an actual signal are all negative.
- The magnitude of the noise are all much smaller than that of any signal value.

How can I sort my array so that

- The values that corresponds to actual signals all come *before* the noise values.
- The order of the values that corresponds to actual signals are determined by their original ordering in the given array.

For example

```
input = [-0.0002, -0.00058, -0.28, -0.0008, -0.25,-0.0006,-0.00004,-0.26]
output = [-0.28, -0.25, -0.26, -0.0002, -0.00058,-0.0008, -0.0006,-0.00004]
```

Comment: I don't understand why the output is in that order.

Comment: Output created with dummy values. I am interested insignificant values. In above example there are only three significant values.

Comment: @User1551892: I think you shouldn't use the word "significant", because it has a technical meaning in statistics, and your question is not about statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a logical array `ind` that indicates the position of local minima:

```
d = diff(y);
ind = [1, d(1 : end) < 0] & [d(1 : end) > 0, 1];
```

Construct the output by first extracting the values that are local minima, then the others (logical negation of `ind`), and put them together in one array:

```
output = [y(ind), y(~ind)]
```

Comment: why you are taking diff of y. Actually y is diff(x).

Comment: Well, you called the variable `y`, so I used `y`. I take the `diff` because for discrete data, a local minimum is defined as a place where the preceding difference is negative and the following difference is positive. You want the local minima of `y`, right? If not, you have to edit your question to explain better what you want. We can't read your mind, you know?

Answer (score 0):

it's logically very simple. how you state it all your data must be less than some treshold.

try this:

```
input = [-0.0002, -0.00058, -0.28, -0.0008, -0.25,-0.0006,-0.00004,-0.26]
output = [-0.28, -0.25, -0.26, -0.0002, -0.00058,-0.0008, -0.0006,-0.00004]

is_data=input<-0.001;    
res = [input(is_data) input(~is_data)]
res - output % = 0!
```